# How can i use my IUnitOfWork with a BaseController

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using `UnitOfWork` and `Repository` pattern together. I have a base `Repository` where i handle CRUD operations, and i have `<TEntityRepository>` for each domain. After all, I am putting all together and using my `UnitOfWork.SaveChanges()` method to handle those CRUD operations from one pipeline.

Here is my UnitOfWork

```
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly ProductContext _context;

        public UnitOfWork(ProductContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            Products = new ProductRepository(_context);
            LypProducts = new LypProductRepository(_context);
            CompetitorProducts = new CompetitorProductRepository(_context);
            CompetitorProductLogs = new CompetitorProductLogRepository(_context);
            Competitors = new CompetitorRepository(_context);
            OldProducts = new OldProductRepository(_context);
            Manufacturers = new ManufacturerRepository(_context);
            Categories = new CategoryRepository(_context);
        }

        public ProductRepository Products { get; private set; }
        public LypProductRepository LypProducts { get; private set; }
        public CompetitorProductRepository CompetitorProducts { get; private set; }
        public CompetitorProductLogRepository CompetitorProductLogs { get; private set; }
        public CompetitorRepository Competitors { get; private set; }
        public OldProductRepository OldProducts { get; private set; }
        public ManufacturerRepository Manufacturers { get; private set; }
        public CategoryRepository Categories { get; private set; }

        public int SaveChanges()
        {   
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Here is my IUnitOfWork

```
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        ProductRepository Products { get; }
        LypProductRepository LypProducts { get; }
        CompetitorProductRepository CompetitorProducts { get; }
        CompetitorProductLogRepository CompetitorProductLogs { get; }
        CompetitorRepository Competitors { get; }
        OldProductRepository OldProducts { get; }
        ManufacturerRepository Manufacturers { get; }
        CategoryRepository Categories { get; }
        int SaveChanges();
    }
```

Here is my Repository

```
    public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly DbContext Context;

        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

        public TEntity Get(int id)
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(int id)
        {
            return await Context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
        }
        // Other CRUD operations located here.
   }
```

Here is my IRepository

```
        TEntity Get(int id);
        Task<TEntity> GetAsync(int id);
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
        Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync();
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
        TEntity SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
        void Add(TEntity entity);
        void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
        void Remove(TEntity entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
```

i am using  this UnitOfWork like this in background jobs without any problem:

```
            using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new ProductContext()))
            {
                var products = unitOfWork.Products.GetAll();
                var oldProducts = unitOfWork.OldProducts.GetAll();
                var manufacturers = unitOfWork.Manufacturers.GetAll();
                var categories = unitOfWork.Categories.GetAll();


                // do stuff

                unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            }
```

However, i dont know how to use this logic in WebApi projects. I am frontend engineer, so have no profesional experience on creating WebApis so any help on using this logic in a base controller will appreciated.

Comment: Typically you would just configure your Dependency Injection service to produce scoped instance of your ProductContext and UnitOfWork.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the tags I am assuming you're working with `asp.net core` project. In this case you can leverage the dependency injection mechanism that comes with it. Basically you register all your repositories and your unit of work in `Startup` class and inject it into constructors where you need them. The trick for unit of work will be it's lifetime scope. You likely want it to persist between calls while you handle one single request - this is achieved by `Scoped` lifetime.

#### Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ProductContext>(o => o.UseInMemoryDatabase("test")); // this is just to prove a point, your EF setup will be different
    // register all your services here
    services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(); // Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests. 
    services.AddTransient<LypProductRepository>(); // and so on and so forth...

    // your other initialisation code here
}
```

#### UnitOfWork.cs

```cs
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ProductContext _context;
    public ProductRepository ProductRepository { get; set; }

    public UnitOfWork(ProductContext context, ProductRepository productRepository, ...other repositories) // since you are registering your services in Startup.cs anyway, why not leverage DI here?
    {
        _context = context;
        ProductRepository = productRepository;
        // your other repositories
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Although the result is the same with the UnitOfWork creating all the Repository instances, instead of having them passed to the UnitOfWork constructor.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft indeed, no difference in the snippet provided. Doing it this way might however aid unit testing (given OP registers interfaces instead) in the bigger picture. Also I was hoping to show an example of how one would have services injected as well

Comment: Yes.  And I would much rather see a set of business services consuming the DbContext directly than this tier of useless intermediate repository types.

Comment: Straight Savage